# Where can I find the live standings of the Grand Chess Tour?

Tags: tournament, websites

The final stage of the Grand Chess Tour is being held these days at London and I was wondering who's going to win the general prize of the series.

In the [official website](http://grandchesstour.com/tour-standings) I could just find the standings after the Sinquefield cup, but I couldn't find the live standings updated after each game. I know that I can calculate them by hand, but I'd like to find a website with them.

Where can I find the live standings of the Grand Chess Tour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the London Chess Classics website, there is a link to the [GCT Estimated Standings](http://www.londonchessclassic.com/downloads/gct/GrandChessTourEstimatedStandings.pdf)

An estimate is the best you can get though:

> ... The points actually allocated will be determined by tiebreaks which cannot be calculated until the end of the tournament...